# Directshow: Direct connect to VMR-9

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

I wrote a simple program for webcam capture using Directshow.
Here is its graph:
[image]

Here I create Smart Tee and connect it to my webcam.  The first output pin goes to Null renderer, the second I try to connect to VMR-9 (Windowsless mode).  After run I see Color Space  Converter between the tee and VMR-9. Why? Does not VMR-9 support a direct connect for RGB24?

Answer (score 4):

You will typically see a conversion filter there because the video renderer not only does not support 24-bit RGB, but it also has additional requirements - its upstream connection filter needs to [support extended strides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388901). Many filters don't support that and Color Space Converter Filter works it around.

> The Video Mixing Renderer filter (VMR-7 and VMR-9) will connect with any format that is **supported by the graphics hardware** on the system. [...] The VMR-9 always uses Direct3D for rendering, and allocates the underlying Direct3D surfaces when the upstream filter connects.
>
> The graphics hardware may **require a larger surface stride than the image width**. In that case, the VMR requests a new format by calling QueryAccept. [...]